# filter out np.nan and keep max order_date if customer has a "score"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame({
'acct_num': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3],
'score': [np.nan, np.nan, 300, 250, np.nan, 275, 400, 450, 9998, np.nan, np.nan],
'order_date': ['2021-05-11 20:29:22.656','2021-04-15 10:15:20.444',
               '2021-03-18 03:29:22.400', '2021-02-21 22:05:22.399',
               '2021-05-05 12:01:19.699','2021-04-19 18:16:22.493',
               '2021-04-19 05:12:12.837', '2021-04-19 04:22:19.199',
               '2021-04-19 03:58:11.121', '2021-02-01 14:29:22.656',
               '2021-03-08 13:03:22.653']})
```

Here is what the output should look like:

```
pd.DataFrame({
'acct_num': [1, 2, 3],
'score': [300, 450, np.nan],
'order_date': ['2021-03-18 03:29:22.400','2021-04-19 04:22:19.199',
              '2021-02-01 14:29:22.656']})
```

The logic in filtering this data is the following:

1. group by account number and return the max order_date where the score is not Null.
2. If all scores are null for a given acct_num, return the max order_date and a score of Null.
3. If the acct_num orders twice in the same day, return the highest score of that day and the order_date (with time stamp). UNLESS the score is 9998, then that score should be ignored if there are other non Null scores on the same day.

Comment: Can the value of score become negative ever in your dataframe? I mean do you have negative values as well?

Comment: No, the scores actually refer to credit scores. No negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly we will get the value of **'acct_num'** column where `score==9998` then we will check the count of **'acct_num'** whether it is greater than 1 or not:

```
val=df.loc[df['score']==9998,'acct_num'].values[0]
cond=df.loc[df['acct_num']==val,'acct_num'].count()>1
```

Finally use `groupby()` and boolean masking:

```
result=df[(df['score']!=9998) | (cond==True)].groupby('acct_num')[['order_date','score']].max()
```

Comment: You can't filter out 9998 because if its the only non Null value for an acct_num it needs to be returned.

Comment: Updated my answer...kindly have a look **:)**

Answer (score 0):

according with the rules then group by acct_num and then examine each group looking for the max score and max order date and output the data.

```
 grouped2=df.groupby('acct_num').groups
 for group in grouped2:
     filter=(df['acct_num']==group) & (df['score']!=9998)
     max_score=df[filter]['score'].max()
     max_order_date=df[filter]['order_date'].max()
    print(max_score,max_order_date)
```

output:

```
 300.0 2021-05-11 20:29:22.656
 450.0 2021-05-05 12:01:19.699
 nan   2021-03-08 13:03:22.653
```

Comment: I'm not sure this works. In reality, my dataframe is > 4 million records, this was running for 30 mins so I stopped it.

Comment: you can do the same thing in sql which will aggregate very fast.  Usually with data that large I would recommend reading your dataframe in chunks then process an account at a time putting the results into a list.

Comment: my guess is the filter is running very slowly over the large dataset.